# help me understand partial matching in data.frame column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have bumped into a strange problem today. The reason might be a basic thing I am not aware of but still I am pretty curious how this problem could possibly arise and what could be the solution.

So, imagine we have a data frame like this one here.

```
abc<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c",
"c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c")

count<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)

xyz<-c("x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","y","y","z","z","z","z","z","z",
"z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z")

total_df<-as.data.frame(cbind(abc,count,xyz))
```

As you can see we have 3 variables and 30 observations here.

If you are gonna send these lines into R then you will see that each variable contains 3 factors so the variables are all factorized:

```
total_df$abc
total_df$count
total_df$xyz
```

Or just simply check it this way:

```
class(total_df$abc)
class(total_df$count)
class(total_df$xyz)
```

Now in the next step I wanted to call one of these variables simply this way:

```
total_df$count
```

And accidentally I realized that the following lines:

```
total_df$coun
total_df$cou
total_df$co
total_df$c
```

… so these lines give me exactly the very same result as the line 'total_df$count'. How is this possible? Is this phenomenon normal at all? I have not created a variable named ’cou’ and R still recognizes it?! Do I forget something here? It really worries me because this problem could cause serious headaches later... Is there a way to evade/solve this problem? I mean, telling R to recognize only the variable ’count’? And I do not want all the other - in my opinion 'fake' - variables like ’coun’, ’cou’ to be recognized at all.

The problem occured in the other two main variables, 'abc' and 'xyz' as well.

I have 2.12.0 type of R by the way.

Thank you and have a nice day.
Laszlo.